# I'm trying to build an Android App to connect to a HC-05 bluetooth device using Kotlin, but i cant make it connect

Tags: android, kotlin, arduino, bluetooth

This is the MainActivity.Kt file, i am following the Android Developer Documentation, I cant figure out why it wont connect, I am an absolute Newbie, Please Help.

I've tried the discoverability and bonding and fetching all bonded devices and it work fine, but i cant get it to connect, i used the device's MAC Adress directly to help simplify things, but nothing work still, All permissions are also set in the Manifest, BT, BT_ADMIN, and LOCATION. Thanks

```
package com.example.btconnection

import android.app.Activity
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1
    val MY_UUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device Doesn't support BT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
                val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
            }
        }

        connectbutton.setOnClickListener {
            ConnectThread(bluetoothAdapter!!.getRemoteDevice("00:19:10:08:4D:F0"))
        }
    }

    private inner class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice) : Thread() {

        private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
            device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)
        }

        override fun run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
            bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()

            mmSocket?.use { socket ->
                // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
                socket.connect()
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
                // the connection in a separate thread.
               // manageMyConnectedSocket(socket)
            }
        }

        // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
        fun cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket?.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("Error", "Could not close the client socket", e)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(bluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"BT Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"BT Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this,"BT Enable Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the HC-05 service `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`? This officially known as the [Serial Port Profile (SPP)](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/) but Android refer to it as [RFCOMM](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket)

Answer (score 0):

I looked closely at the HC-05 and realized that it connect for like a 500 Millisecond and disconnect and I figured that it connects then disconnects after a very short period of time, and when I checked the code, the function `fun cancel()` closes the socket instantly after its been connected.
So the socket remain open for the data stream to be sent out.

Now the button only does this:

```
 connectbutton.setOnClickListener {
            btSocket = bluetoothAdapter!!.getRemoteDevice("00:19:10:08:4D:F0").createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)
//            ConnectThread(bluetoothAdapter!!.getRemoteDevice("00:19:10:08:4D:F0"))
            try {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
            btSocket!!.connect()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```